# Arduino (rosserial) node hangs during I2C reading + PWM

Tags: ros, arduino, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to troubleshoot a strange problem for a few days now. I've got a ROS Kinetic node running on a Raspberry Pi 3 (Ubuntu Mate). I'm utilizing the rosserial_arduino package to handle communication between the Arduino and my master node. Current setup is basically an Arduino Mega 2560 with a SEED Studio Motor Shield powering 2 wheels, plus an ITG3205/ADXL345/HMC5883L 9-DOF chip. I currently have two publishers set up - one outputting twistStamped messages and one chatter topic outputting loop iterations and debug information.  I've got one subscriber set up receiving an int16 message from a homespun teleop script - basically listening for keys 2,4,5,6,8.

Everything works perfectly if there is no power to the motor shield (I'm using an external 6v pack). I am able to echo out twist messages which are directly linked to the xyz axis on my gyro and accel. My chatter topic shows me my current loop iteration and when I send key commands I see  them echoing out as well. Similarly, if the motor power is off, I still get LED signals on the shield showing the current motor states.

If I turn on power supply to the motors and send a signal other than "full stop" which is key 5, everything hangs up. it might take a few loops but it will hang within 1-4 seconds of the motor signal being sent and received. Resetting the board alleviates the issue and all my topics begin to send/receive again.

I have traced this problem down to the ITG3205 portion that performs the I2C communication (itgRead function) - specifically after the first call to Wire.endTransmission().

Any ideas? I've tried swapping out the arduino, the shield, and the 9-dof chip with no success. As long as i've got wheels are spinning, everything hangs on gyro read. I've included relevant code snippets below.

**Motor Shield code. Only included forward for brevity.**

```
void SeeedMotorV2::allStop()
{
    digitalWrite(leftmotorspeed,0);
    digitalWrite(rightmotorspeed,0);
      digitalWrite(leftmotorForward,LOW);
     digitalWrite(rightmotorBackward,LOW);
      digitalWrite(leftmotorBackward,LOW);
      digitalWrite(rightmotorForward,LOW);

}

void SeeedMotorV2::forward(int speed)
{
  allStop();
  analogWrite(leftmotorspeed,speed); //pin 10
  analogWrite(rightmotorspeed,speed);//pin 9
  digitalWrite(leftmotorBackward,LOW);//pin 13
  digitalWrite(rightmotorBackward,LOW);//pin 11
  digitalWrite(leftmotorForward,HIGH);//pin 12
  digitalWrite(rightmotorForward,HIGH);//pin 8
}
```

**ITG3205 code snippet.**

```
unsigned char ITG3205::itgRead(char address, char registerAddress)
{
  //This variable will hold the contents read from the i2c device.
  unsigned char data=0;

  //Send the register address to be read.
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  //Send the Register Address
  Wire.write(registerAddress);

  //End the communication sequence.
  Wire.endTransmission();

  //Ask the I2C device for data
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  Wire.requestFrom(address, 1);

  //Wait for a response from the I2C device
  if(Wire.available()){
    //Save the data sent from the I2C device
    data = Wire.read();
  }

  //End the communication sequence.
  Wire.endTransmission();

  //Return the data read during the operation
  return data;
}

//itgAddress = 0x68
//GYRO_XOUT_H = 0x1D
//GYRO_YOUT_L = 0x1DE
int ITG3205::readX(void)
{
  int data=0;
  data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_H)<<8;
  data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_L);

  return data;
}
```

**Main Sketch. Shortened to code in question.**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Vectors.h>
#include <ITG3205.h>
#include <SeeedMotorV2.h>

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>
char base_link[] = "/base_link";


SeeedMotorV2 motors;
ITG3205 gyroscope;


unsigned long timer;
int cntr = 0;
char loops[25];


void cmd_int_vel(const std_msgs::Int16& message)
{
  switch(message.data)
  {
    case 1:
      sendMessage("1");
      break;
    case 2:
      sendMessage("2");
      motors.backward();
      break;
    case 3:
      sendMessage("3");
      break;
    case 4:
      sendMessage("4");
      motors.left();
      break;
    case 5:
      sendMessage("5");
      motors.allStop();
      break;
    case 6:
      sendMessage("6");
      motors.right();
      break;
    case 7:
      sendMessage("7");
      break;
    case 8:
      sendMessage("8");
      motors.forward();
      break;
    case 9:
      sendMessage("9");
      break;
    default:
      sendMessage("Unknown Velocity Command");
      break;
  }
}


ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int16> int_movement("cmd_int_vel", &cmd_int_vel);


ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);


geometry_msgs::TwistStamped twistMsg;
ros::Publisher twists("twists", &twistMsg);


void setup()
{
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
  nh.advertise(twists);
  nh.subscribe(int_movement);
  
  motors.begin();
  
  timer = 0;

  gyroscope.begin();
  gyroscope.calibrate(100, 10);
 
  delay(10);
  nh.spinOnce();
}



void loop()
{
  sprintf(loops, "%i", cntr);
  cntr++;
  sendMessage(loops);
  
  Vector acc2 = accelerometer.readNormalize();

  Vector gyr = gyroscope.readNormalize();


  twistMsg.header.frame_id = base_link;
  twistMsg.twist.linear.x = acc2.XAxis;
  twistMsg.twist.linear.y = acc2.YAxis;
  twistMsg.twist.linear.z = acc2.ZAxis;
  twistMsg.twist.angular.x = gyr.XAxis;
  twistMsg.twist.angular.y = gyr.YAxis;
  twistMsg.twist.angular.z = gyr.ZAxis;
  
  twistMsg.header.stamp = nh.now();
  twists.publish(&twistMsg);
  
 
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);

}

void sendMessage(char* message)
{

  str_msg.data = message;
  chatter.publish(&str_msg);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250366/arduino-(rosserial)-node-hangs-during-i2c-reading-+-pwm/) by [david.1982](https://answers.ros.org/users/28846/david.1982/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my testing, it appears rosserial_arduino can subscribe to both Twist and TwistStamped messages correctly; but, the callback will not work if the message type is TwistStamped.

---

Originally posted by [Void](https://answers.ros.org/users/28605/void/) with karma: 71 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0